# ¿Cómo controlo elementos de mi activity desde una card del recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, xml

Quiero poder cambiar la visibilidad de un componente de mi activity desde el `onclick` del `adapter` de mi `recycler`.

Por ejemplo, mi `recycler` muestra una lista de colores, quiero que cada que haga click sobre uno de esos colores se realice un `setbackground` en el componente principal del `activity`.

Answer (score 0):

tenes que haces algunas cosas. Primero en RecyclerView, tenes que definir una interfaz Listener que se va a usar para comunicar el evento onClick a la actividad.

asi:

```
public interface OnColorClickListener {
  void onColorClick(int color);
}
```

Después, en RecyclerView, tenes que definir un campo para contener el objeto listener y un setter para setear el listener.

asi:

```
    private OnColorClickListener listener;
    
    public void setOnColorClickListener(OnColorClickListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }
```

En RecyclerView, tenes que llamar al método onColorClick del listener desde el evento onClick de la vista que representa un color.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ColorViewHolder holder, int position) {
  // ...
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      listener.onColorClick(color);
    }
  });
}
```

En activity, tenes que implementar la interfaz Listener y anular el método onColorClick. Dentro del método, puede usar el color pasado como argumento para establecer el color de fondo del componente principal de la actividad.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnColorClickListener {
  // ...

  @Override
  public void onColorClick(int color) {
    View mainComponent = findViewById(R.id.main_component);
    mainComponent.setBackgroundColor(color);
  }
}
```

Y por ultimo, en activity, tenes que configurar el listener en el adaptador RecyclerView.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
ColorAdapter adapter = new ColorAdapter();
adapter.setOnColorClickListener(this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```